# In codeigniter how to do pagination on searched values

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

list page

```
<div class="container">
<!--search criteria-->
<div class="alert alert-info">
<form method="post" class="form-inline" action="<?php echo base_url();?>/admin/area/index" id="form_search">
        <div class="pull-left" style="color:#666;">Show Results:&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <select name="limit" id="limit" style="width:50px;">
          <option value="10"<?php if(10==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?>>10</option>
          <option value="20" <?php if(20==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?>>20</option>
          <option value="30" <?php if(30==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?>>30</option>
          <option value="40" <?php if(40==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?>>40</option>
          <option value="50" <?php if(50==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?>>50</option>
        </select>
    </div>
<label style="color:#666;">&nbsp;&nbsp;Search By City:&nbsp;&nbsp;</label>
<select id="cityId" name="cityId" >
               <option value='0'> --All-- </option>
                   <?php 
                  foreach($cityOptionList as $city) {  ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $city['id']?>" <?php if($city['id']==$cityId) echo "selected";?>><?php echo $city['name']?></option>
                  <?php } ?> 
              </select>
</form>
</div>
<!--search criteria end-->
    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sl.no</th>
            <th>Area Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Actions</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php $i=1; foreach($areaList as $area) {?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $area->areaName;?></td>
            <td class="center"><?php echo $area->city_name;?></td>
            <td class="center">
            <a  href="<?php echo base_url();?>admin/area/edit/<?php echo $area->areaId ; ?>">
            <i class="icon-edit" style="font-size:16px;"></i></a>
        <!--    <a  href="#" data-id="<?php echo $area->areaId;?>">
                <i class="icon-trash" style="font-size:16px;"></i></a>-->
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php $i++; } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>   
<?php echo $links;?>            
</div>
<!--/container--> 
<!--=== End Content Part ===-->
<script>
$(function() {
   $("#cityId").change(function() {
     $("#form_search").submit();
   });

    $("#limit").change(function() {
     $("#form_search").submit();
   });
  /* 
   $(".pagination").click(function(){
          alert("hi");
         $("#form_search").submit();
   })
   */
 });
</script>
```

controller code

```
 public function index(){
        $searchParam = '';
        if(! empty($this->input->get('q'))){
            $searchParam = $this->input->get('q');
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('cityId'))){
            $search_city= $this->input->post('cityId');
        }
        $data['title'] = 'Area';
        $data['action'] = 'admin/area/';
        $data['searchParam'] = $searchParam;
        $data['arealist'] = $this->getList();
        $this->load->view('admin/header',$data);
        $this->load->view('admin/area/view.php', $data);
        $this->load->view('admin/footer',$data);
    }

    protected function getList(){
        $stateId = $this->session->userdata('stateId');
        $searchParam = '';
        $search_city = '';
        if(! empty($this->input->get('q'))){
            $searchParam = $this->input->get('q');
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('cityId'))){
            $search_city= $this->input->post('cityId');
        }
        if(!empty($this->input->post('limit'))){
            $limit= $this->input->post('limit');
        }
        else
        {
            $limit = 10;
        }
         $config = $this->config->item('pagination');  
        $config = array();
        $config["base_url"] = base_url() . "admin/area/index/";
        $config["total_rows"] = $this->area_model->getArea(0, 0, $searchParam, 1,$search_city);
        $totalCount = $config['total_rows'];
        $config["per_page"] = $limit;
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $config['use_page_numbers']  = TRUE;
        $config['reuse_query_string'] = TRUE;
        $data['cityId'] = $search_city;
        $data['limit_selected'] = $limit;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $page = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 1;              
        $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
        $data["areaList"] = $this->area_model->getArea($config["per_page"], $page, $searchParam,0,$search_city);
        $data['cityOptionList'] = $this->area_model->getCityByStateId($stateId);    
        return $this->load->view('admin/area/list.php', $data, true);

    }
```

in list page when i change the city then the data is getting according to city and displaying in list page and the pagination is displayed if there are more than selected records.
The problem is when i click on pagination link for searched values then all the records are loading instead of search values.
In pagination how to get the searched values only if the search is applied on the records.

Comment: Off topic: a shorter way to do this: <?php if(20==$limit_selected) echo "selected";?> is <?= ($limit_selected == 20 ? 'selected' : '') ?>. Because, <?php echo $some ?> means the same thing as <?= $some ?>. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry missed your whole question. To incudle your search parameters as filters in paging you need to add them.Refer below link to see what setting in config you need to change.

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html#customizing-the-pagination

you need to change below setting.

```
 $config[‘reuse_query_string’] = FALSE;
```

I'm guessing from your code that the search form will do a POST action when it gets submitted by the user. After the user submitted the form, of course it will work. Because they just did a POST request, and you fetch the search query from $_POST by using $this->input->post('user_input') or something similar. But then, when they try to navigate to another page by clicking on the page number link (which is a GET request), the search fails because the superglobal $_POST array is empty.

A solution to solve this problem is to set a session value (I recommend that you use CodeIgniter's Session Class) based on the user input and instead of using the search query from $_POST, and use the one stored in session instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this change code with your requirment and your table

set controller this way

```
       <?php
class pagination extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->database();
        $this->load->library('pagination');
        $this->load->model('pagination_model');
    }

    public function index()
    {
        //pagination settings
        $config['base_url'] = site_url('pagination/index');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->count_all('tbl_books');
        $config['per_page'] = "3";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 3;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = '«';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = '»';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;

        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config["per_page"], $data['page'], NULL);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        // load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }

    function search()
    {
        // get search string
        $search = ($this->input->post("book_name"))? $this->input->post("book_name") : "NIL";

        $search = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : $search;

        // pagination settings
        $config = array();
        $config['base_url'] = site_url("pagination/search/$search");
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books_count($search);
        $config['per_page'] = "5";
        $config["uri_segment"] = 4;
        $choice = $config["total_rows"]/$config["per_page"];
        $config["num_links"] = floor($choice);

        // integrate bootstrap pagination
        $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
        $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
        $config['first_link'] = false;
        $config['last_link'] = false;
        $config['first_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['first_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['prev_link'] = 'Prev';
        $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev">';
        $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
        $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['last_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['last_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="#">';
        $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
        $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li>';
        $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $data['page'] = ($this->uri->segment(4)) ? $this->uri->segment(4) : 0;
        // get books list
        $data['booklist'] = $this->pagination_model->get_books($config['per_page'], $data['page'], $search);

        $data['pagination'] = $this->pagination->create_links();

        //Load view
        $this->load->view('pagination_view',$data);
    }
}
?>
```

set model this way

```
       <?php
class pagination_model extends CI_Model{

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    //fetch books
    function get_books($limit, $start, $st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%' limit " . $start . ", " . $limit;
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->result();
    }

    function get_books_count($st = NULL)
    {
        if ($st == "NIL") $st = "";
        $sql = "select * from tbl_books where name like '%$st%'";
        $query = $this->db->query($sql);
        return $query->num_rows();
    }
}
?>
```

then your veiw page looks like

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>CodeIgniter Pagination Example with Search Query Filter</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url("bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"); ?>">

    <style type="text/css">
    .bg-border {
        border: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-radius: 4px 4px;
        padding: 15px 15px;
    }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 well">
        <?php 
        $attr = array("class" => "form-horizontal", "role" => "form", "id" => "form1", "name" => "form1");
        echo form_open("pagination/search", $attr);?>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input class="form-control" id="book_name" name="book_name" placeholder="Search for Book Name..." type="text" value="<?php echo set_value('book_name'); ?>" />
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input id="btn_search" name="btn_search" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" value="Search" />
                    <a href="<?php echo base_url(). "index.php/pagination/index"; ?>" class="btn btn-primary">Show All</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 bg-border">
            <table class="table table-striped table-hover">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th>#</th>
                    <th>Book Name</th>
                    <th>Author Name</th>
                    <th>ISBN</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <?php for ($i = 0; $i < count($booklist); ++$i) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?php echo ($page+$i+1); ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->name; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->author; ?></td>
                    <td><?php echo $booklist[$i]->isbn; ?></td>
                </tr>
                <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
            <?php echo $pagination; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```